# Should a RESTful API return 400 or 404 when passed an invalid id

Tags: rest

When building a RESTful API and a user provides an **id** of resource that does not exist, should you return `404 Not Found` or `400 Bad Request`.

For example:

```
https://api.domain.com/v1/resource/foobar
```

Where **foobar** does not exist.

Comment: When designing api's it is important to be self documenting more so when there is error it is important for api provided to guide consumer a course correction. Throwing 404 is first of all wrong documentation but also misleading. Also its important to note that URL, HEADERS, BODY are all part of request and if any one of them is malformed then I will prefer api provider to return unambiguous response so I can course correct. Also I would prefer well formatted req entering my inner application for that matter even datastore to avoid unnecessary surprises.

Comment: Use 404  and follow https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1 :
  "The response header fields allow the server to pass additional
   information about the response beyond what is placed in the
   status-line.  These header fields give information about the server,
   about further access to the target resource, or about related
   resources."

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I would return 404 in case of resource does not exist(means the url path is wrong) and i will return 400 only if the rest call is made with some invalid data (@PathParam) for example
https://api.domain.com/v1/profile/test@email : here i am trying to get profile of email id, but the email itself is wrong, so I will return 400.
https://api.domain.com/v1/profile1111/test@email.com will return 404 because the url path is invalid.

Comment: Why would you validate the email in this case?

Comment: This answer is incorrect.
According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.5:

10.4.1 400 Bad Request

   The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
   modifications.

10.4.5 404 Not Found

   The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No
   indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or
   permanent. 

So first example should return 404 and second 400.

Comment: To add to @Przemo: IMO, in case you do validate email, then the first example should also return 400, but if the email format was OK and the record with this email doesn't exist, then return 404.

Comment: Explanation of my downvote: Either the resource exists for the given identifier, then a GET request shall be returned without syntax validation of the identifier (usually HTTP 200 OK). Or it does not exist, then 404 shall be returned. You can impose such validation of the identifier when processing an HTTP PUT. Including it in a GET is the wrong approach.

Comment: It may be "incorrect" if you want to follow the REST-idea completely (which is understandable). But then you have the problem that a client of your API has now way to distingish those two cases (is the URL itself wrong, or did he just submitted an invalid path parameter?)

So even when you are technically right @Przemo I think you can make a strong case to deviate from the "correct" way for the sake of clarity - so send 400 to make it clear that there was something wrong with the provided parameters, while the url itself was correct

Answer (score 25):

Should be 404 ( Not Found ). 400 is used if you can't fulfill the request due to bad syntax, however for your case, the syntax is correct, however there is no resource foobar.

You can use 400 if user uses non-existent API like below :

```
https://api.domain.com/v1/nonexistAPI/xyz/xyz
```

You can also refer to this [REST API Design Blog](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_what_about_errors) which tell you how to design your REST error codes.

Comment: Then I can't tell if the route is wrong or the item is not found. Both of them will give me 404 ??

Comment: @Wahid Bitar: Usually you receive an OpenAPI specification which tells you the available routes. Using that, you can assert that your routes are correct as per specification, and you can write tests for that.

Comment: @Rudy: Your example with "nonexistAPI" should also return HTTP 404, for the very same reason that you explained in the second sentence of your answer :-) i.e. it is a syntactically valid HTTP request.

Comment: funny thing, the linked blog is throwing 404 :D

Answer (score 17):

`404 Not Found` is the proper answer I think, `400` is more about the body of the requests and not the resource identifier, so for example you can send that by validation errors.

Comment: IMO, if, for example, a GUID is expected as a resource identifier, but a string that does not correspond to the GUID format arrives in the method, then HTTP 400 Bad Request should be returned.

Comment: @AlexDEV.pro I think you are right if you have a strict GUID format that will never change.

Answer (score 9):

Is it a valid request? Can the id of the resource exist? Is it formatted as a proper id? Is it syntactically correct? etc.. If so then you can use, `404 Not Found`. Otherwise `400 Bad Request` is more suitable.

Answer (score 9):

According to the RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4)
the API should return 404 when

> "The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI",

which is your example.

400 would be when the resource is found, but the request itself is malformed.

For instance:
i.
https://api.domain.com/v1/resource/foobar

where foobar DOES NOT exist should return 404

ii.
https://api.domain.com/v1/resource/foobar
where foobar DOES exist, but the request is wrong (`{age:"NOTANINTEGER"}`, a `string` instead of an `int` for example), it should return 400.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 4):

`404` would be a more common practice one. Its for `Resource Not Found`. In your case the particular URL is not found.

`400` is generally used for `Bad Request`. You can use this one for any bad request. For eg. `MissingRequiredQueryParameter`, `InvalidInput`.