# HTTP 400 vs HTTP 404 for a malformed URI api request

Tags: api, http, specifications

So imagine we have an endpoint called `/guest/{guestId}`. This endpoint has a GET function where if you provide it a **guestId** it will return an object with all of the guest information.

The question is what should be returned in each of these scenarios -

guestId = "" leading to `/guest/`
guestId = "invalidId" leading to `/guest/invalidId`

The HTTP 1.1 documentation seems to leave room open for either in terms of passing an invalid ID but suggests a 404 when the `guestId` is blank. For an invalid ID, it's technically hitting the endpoint but just giving it malformed syntax which points towards a 400 but at the same time provides the server with an invalid URI which points to a 404.

What is factually and not opinion-basedly correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a RESTful API return 400 or 404 when passed an invalid id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378624/should-a-restful-api-return-400-or-404-when-passed-an-invalid-id)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no room for interpretation here. The resource at `/guest/invalidId` doesn't exist and should return a 404.

The request itself wasn't really 'malformed' in anyway, it just used a uri that was pointing to a non-existent resource. It's malformed, maybe in the perspective of your specific application (it's not a valid id), but it is not from the perspective of the HTTP protocol.

As a general rule this might help as well:

When you want to emit an error to a client, and the client is responsible. You'll want to emit an error in the 400-499 range. If you can't find a good specific error to meet your specific error condition, only then you'll really want to use 400, as in practice it's kind of used as a status code when nothing else really is fitting.

Comment: Nice, that clears things up. Thank you very much for your answer!