# BadRequest vs NotFound when the resource is a sheet but the user required is not found

Tags: rest, api

I'm just having a discussion here with my colleague regarding what is the best response to return when requesting a specific resource i.e. a datasheet for example, and the url is valid but part of the process when processing this datasheet is to get a specific user which may not be found.

I found this question on SO: [Should a RESTful API return 400 or 404 when passed an invalid id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378624/should-a-restful-api-return-400-or-404-when-passed-an-invalid-id)

My understanding is that if the request is valid i.e. the url and the parameters pass to it, it should return a 404 (NotFound) if the user is not found.

But my colleague's point is that the datasheet is the resource and therefore since the user requested is not found, it should actually be considered as 400 (BadRequest)

Can someone clarify what it should actually be?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Although BadRequest might make sense initially it does not fit the definition of a 400.

> [400](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html): The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

Reserve a 400 for when the request is missing required fields, an incorrect data type was provided, etc.

In your case, it sounds like the user has made a valid request but that part of the data needed for completion is not found (I'm guessing this is a part of the Uri).  This sounds a lot more like a 404, which is perfectly valid when something other than the specified resource is not found.

> [404](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html): The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.

The specifics of what was not found can be expressed in the error code or the error message.